# Very simple mod_rewrite help

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a directory called fb and a script inside called like.php. I'd like to have the get-id passed to the like-file using mod_rewrite.

**mypage.com/fb/like.php?id=5** would be **mypage.com/fb/like/5**

My (not working) htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule /fb/like/([0-9]+) /fb/like.php?id=$1
```

Does anyone see what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the slash at the beginning of your match and replace patterns like so:

```
RewriteRule fb/like/([0-9]+) fb/like.php?id=$1
```

`mypage.com/` is the domain name, so the string that gets matched is `fb/like/5`

Also consider using the carat at the start of your match string so that it will match `fb` but not `fffb`:

```
 RewriteRule ^fb/like/([0-9]+) fb/like.php?id=$1
```

Here's a **[short guide](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite)** to mod_rewrite I've found helpful.

**Edit for your follow-up question:**

To match mypage.com/something/fb/like/5, you can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/fb/like/([0-9]+) $1/fb/like.php?id=$2
```

This saves the first directory as $1. `[^/]+` means match one or more characters that are not a slash. Put this .htaccess file in the root directory of your domain.

Alternatively, you can use the second-to-last rule and put that .htaccess file in the "something" subdirectory. Hope that makes sense.

Or you can write a rule to match simply `like.php/([0-9]+)` so that it'll work no matter what the directory path looks like. You can go even more generic and make this apply to any PHP file, not just `like.php`. It really depends on how you want your site to work.

Comment: Thank you. That worked on our live-server. But it does not seemst to work on our developer-server. The url there looks like this: http://modx.cat.no/golfhistorie/fb/like.php?id=5. How should the rewriterule be written then?

Comment: With your original rule it would match `golfhistorie/fb/like.php?id=5` and replace it with `/fb/like/5` whereas you really wanted to replace it with `golfhistorie/fb/like/5`. I edited my answer with the modified rule that will do this.